# How To Mutate Variables Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, r5rs, mutability

I'm trying to sum a list using mutable objects for an assignment.`let`is used here to allow me to mutate `x` the total sum and `counter`. I'm not very well versed with scheme hence the use `if` statements for each number in the list `lst`:

```
(define lst (list 1 2 3 4 5))

(let mut ((counter 0))
 (let ((x (car lst)))

  (if (= counter 4)
      x)
  (if (= 0 counter)
    (+ x (cadr lst)))
  (if (= 1 counter)
      (display (caddr lst)) ;test
      (+ x (caddr lst)))
  (if (= 2 counter)
      (+ x (caddr lst)))  

  (set-car! lst (cdr lst))   
  (mut (+ counter 1))
  )
)
```

however when I run the code I get an error

```
+: contract violation
      expected: number?
      given: (mcons 2 (mcons 3 (mcons 4 (mcons 5 '()))))
      argument position: 1st
      other arguments...:
```

However when I check `(caddr lst)` it returns a `3` as expected. **My issue is** why, when run, does `caddr` produce `(mcons 2 (mcons 3 (mcons 4 (mcons 5 '()))))` when applied to an `+` but when not applied it returns `3`

*I am using R5RS*
*edit: I have omitted some of the if statements for conciseness*

Comment: Open your interpreter. Write `(define ls '(1 2 3 4))`. Examine `(car ls)` and `(cdr ls)`. Write `(set-car! ls (cdr ls))`. Examine `(car ls)` and `(cdr ls)` again.

Comment: You've skipped over the fundamentals of Scheme and are trying to write a program in a different language. Start over from chapter 1. (`(if (= counter 4) x)` is *not* the same as `if x == 4: return x`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo I was under the impression that `car` returns a number not a reference, is that not the case?

Comment: There are no "references" in Scheme. [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) is available for free online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out using a whole different implementation *@molbdnilo* was correct that my understanding was flawed. 
here is my implementation if anyone else is struggling with this problem

```
(define (goMut)
  (define mVar 0)
  (define acc 0)

(define (accDo num)
    (set! acc (+ num acc)))

  (for-each (lambda (x) (set! mVar x) (accDo x))
            (list 1 2 3 4 5))
  acc
)
```

Using set! we can apply the value in the list to an external variable and mutate it as we iterate throughout the loop using the function `accDo`. Function template taken from **[SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) pg 107**

Comment: the `if`s in your original code just had to be *nested*, [like so](http://lpaste.net/5655897051754397696). of course a chain of nested `if`s like that is better coded with a `cond`. here you're using the ready-made `for-each` , but originally you did the iteration yourself. (better to learn that way?)